# undefined _post using image as submit

Tags: php, html, forms

im using a form to select from 3 images send a post to a php but the `$_POST['stars'];` is not getting there

```
<form action="components/update_score.php" method="POST">
    <input type="image" name="stars" src="imagenes/th/0.png" value="0" width="120" />
    <input type="image" name="stars" src="imagenes/th/1.png" value="1" width="120" />
    <input type="image" name="stars" src="imagenes/th/2.png" value="2" width="120" />
    <input type="image" name="stars" src="imagenes/th/3.png" value="3" width="120" />
    <input type="hidden" name="war_enemy" value="<?php echo $rws['war_enemy'];?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="user_username" value="<?php echo $user_score;?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="enemy_enemynumber" value="<?php echo $i;?>" />
</form>
```

and on the php

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors",1);
session_start();
if(isset($_POST)){
   echo $_POST['stars'],'<br>';
   echo $_POST['war_enemy'],'<br>';
   echo $_POST['user_username'],'<br>';
   echo $_POST['enemy_enemynumber'],'<br>';
}    
?>
```

sending this give me the Notice: Undefined index: stars i dont want to use a submit button i want to use the images to do so but cant find the way to send the post to the php any help is appreciated

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST)` and see what you have

Comment: A better solution would be to have three different forms--one for each image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 images with the same name change their name or you can use an array renaming stars as stars[] and your code will be something like this:

```
foreach ($_POST['stars'] as $star) {
    echo $star;
}
```

Also instead of src you need to add your image at value and please delete the src as you are using an input.

Comment: You welcome i would be happy if you could mark my answer as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

When you post via an image the x/y coordinates that were clicked on are sent instead the name of the input.

Check `$_POST['stars_x']` and `$_POST['stars_y']`

Comment: using the x and y the post is reciving me data but, i dont know how to use that data

Comment: That's another question, you asked why that was undefined I gave you the right answer. I also don't know what you need to do with that data.

Answer (score 0):

When you make a POST request, you have to encode the data that forms the body of the request in some way.

HTML forms provide three methods of encoding.

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded (the default)
multipart/form-data
text/plain
```

You have to set enctype in form

```
 enctype='multipart/form-data'
```

multipart/form-data is significantly more complicated but it allows entire files to be included in the data.